# Multilingual DXA website running as Azure web app

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5, azure

We trying to set up a DXA 1.5 application in Azure as an Azure web app. This is working fine for one single publication, but what would be the best practice to set up a multilingual website as Azure webapp? Would it be possible to run e.g. all local versions (e.g. /en, /fr, /de) in one single web app?

Thanks!

Comment: we're using WEB 8 as CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXA supports multiple websites in a single web application, see the documentation on this topic: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-7D334E4E-72F7-4AAA-B541-7A845E15C88C

I don't know if there's anything that would be Azure-specific for this, but wouldn't think so.

If you're using Web 8 & Topology Manager, there are no changes needed in the deployed web application.

[EDIT]: Corrected the link :)

Comment: There indeed isn't anything Azure specific in this, the publication mapping for your local versions is all configured through Topology Manager and you would have one singe Azure web app. This is very much the same as you would do it on-premise. If you have connected the Azure web app to your own discovery service, then in Web 8, you can simply use the site wizard to create your localized sites, as all the required settings are there from the installation.